# Possible subspace dimensions of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

What are the possible subspace dimensions of $\mathbb{R}^n$? Am I correct to assume it is all the dimensions from $\mathbb{R}^1, \mathbb{R}^2,...,\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

What about $\mathbb{R}^0$? Is this a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well? And if it is, is this the zero vector?

And what about $\mathbb{R}^n$ Can a space of $n$ dimensions contain a subspace of $n$ dimensions too?

Comment: Yep, correct on all counts. For any $k$ between $0$ and $n$ inclusive, there are subspaces of dimension $k$. In particular, $\mathbb{R}^0$ is the zero vector, and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the whole space.

Comment: I suppose we are speaking about vector spaces, so yes, the origin, or R^0 is a vector space, just control the axiom (which are easily verified). If I say subgroup, I don't mean proper subgroup usually, so it's fine. To find explicitly those vector subspaces, fix a basis and consider the span of $i$ different elements of it, it is a $i$-th dimensional subspace of your space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\Bbb R^n$, you have subspaces with dimensions ranging from $0$ (origin) to $n$ ($\Bbb R^n$ itself).

But you have to be careful: for example, $\Bbb R^2$ is **not** a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$, in fact, it is not even a subset. $\Bbb R^2$ consists of pair of real numbers, and $\Bbb R^3$ consists of triples. What you do have is an isomorphic copy of $\Bbb R^2$ in $\Bbb R^3$, for example, $$\{(x,y,0) \in \Bbb R^3 \}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** for any $k\in \{0,1,\dots n\}$ prove that $\Bbb R^k \times \{0_{\Bbb R^{n-k}}\}$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ of dimension $k$.